# React JS Reusable Collapse/Toggle Function

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I'm trying to make reusable toggle function.

Component initial state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        collapseFirst: false,
        collapseSecond: false
    };
}
```

Toggle function (it should change true/false state based on collapse target clicked):

```
handleToggle = e => {
    const collapseItem = e.target.getAttribute('data-control');
    this.setState({
        [collapseItem]: !this.state.collapseItem
    });
};
```

Rendered elements (using Reactstrap Collapse component):

```
return (
    <div>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.props.toggle} data-control="collapseFirst">
            First Collapse
        </Button>
        <Collapse isOpen={this.props.collapseFirst}>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </Collapse>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.props.toggle} data-control="collapseSecond">
            Second Collapse
        </Button>
        <Collapse isOpen={this.props.collapseSecond}>
            <p>Some another text</p>
        </Collapse>
    </div>
);
```

The problem is that for some reason collapseItem returns expected data-control value but this.state.collapseItem is undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your variable names and values mixed up. Don't worry, especially with some of these ES6 syntaxes it happens to the best of us.

`collapseItem` is not a property on `this.state`. The only properties on the `this.state` object are `collapseFirst` and `collapseSecond`.

In `handleToggle()`, you create a constant called `collapseItem`. This statement:

```
[collapseItem]: !this.state.collapseItem
```

uses the ES6 [computed property syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). This takes the string value of `collapseItem` and creates a property on the object with that value as the key.

Since the value of `collapseItem` should be either `'collapseFirst'` or `'collapseSecond'` this means we'll create a property on the object named either `collapseFirst` or `collapseSecond`, NOT `collapseItem`.

The statement

```
!this.state.collapseItem
```

will always return `true` because, as I said, `this.state.collapseItem` does not exist and will thus return `undefined`. `!undefined` is `true`.

I believe you meant to do:

```
[collapseItem]: !this.state[collapseItem]
```

This will grab the value of the appropriate property from the existing state.

Also, just a side note, when the new state is dependent on the previous state, you should typically use the following `setState()` overload:

```
this.setState(state => ({
    [collapseItem]: !state[collapseItem]
})
```

Read up on that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)